# How to find the nearest index to a specified index in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, indexing

I have two vectors in MATLAB, A and B. B contains some indices (1 to end). I have a random index, R (within the range of the vector indices). I want to write a function (or statement) to choose A[z], where z is the most nearest number (i.e index) to R that is not included in B.

Example:

```
A = [2 3 6 1 9 7 4 5 8]
B = [3 4 5 6 7 8]
R = 5
```

The function must return 3, because the most nearest index is 2, because 5-2<9-5 and 2 is not in B, so A[2] = 3;

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that setdiff and setxor functions sort the result.

```
tmpSet = R - setdiff(1:numel(A),B);
[~,z] = min(abs(tmpSet));
z = tmpSet(z);
Result = A(R-z);
```

The same Example in the question:

```
A = [2 3 6 1 9 7 4 5 8]
B = [3 4 5 6 7 8]
R = 5

tmpSet = 5 - {1 2 9} = {4 3 -4}
z = 2
z = 3
Result = A(5-3) = A(2) = 3
```

Thank you for your ideas.

Answer (score 6):

Improving jacob's answer, here's the correct solution:

```
[result, z] = min(abs(R - setxor(B, 1:numel(A))))
```

And in your case that yields `z = 2` and `result = A(2) = 3`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think it is better to use settdiff instead of setxor. I have changed your code in the following. Please let me know your opinion.

Comment: I am using MATLAB 2012. As stated in setxor documentation, setxor(A,B) = A-B union B-A (symmetric difference). However, in our case I think it does not produce any difference, because B contains numbers in the range.

Answer (score 2):

if I understand correctly, you could do an exclude first, to find the indices not in B, i.e. `excl = A(setxor(B,1:length(A)))`. Then it is easy to get the min like this `excl(min(abs(R-excl)))`.

Comment: `setxor` is definitely the right direction, but the result is wrong. `excl` is supposed to contain indices of `A`, not its values.